# When I click on Data Dictionary, it brings up a blank Excel spreadsheet

Tags: metadata, collegescorecard

When I click on [Data Dictionary in the College Scorecard](http://collegescorecard.ed.gov/data/documentation), it brings up a blank Excel spreadsheet. Where can I find the Data Dictionary information?

Comment: The Data Dictionary in the College Scorecard.  https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/data/documentation/

Answer (score 1):

[That file](https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/assets/CollegeScorecardDataDictionary.xlsx) is fine:

[image]

Two things may be incorrect:

1. There is something wrong with your browser downloading it. Set your browser settings to ask what to do with a download ([example for PDF files for all browsers](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001114.htm)), then save the file to disk, and open it in Excel.
2. It is an **.xlsx** file, not **.xls**. If you have an older version of Excel, you may need to install the [Microsoft Office Compatibility Pack for Word, Excel, and PowerPoint File Formats](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3) to be able to open the newer file format.